# drupal_add_html_head adds the last single metatag from the loop

Tags: php, drupal-7

I need to add two meta tags for a custom theme in Drupal. When adding drupal_add_html_head inside a loop, it only adds the last item from the array as metatags.

```
  foreach ($metatags as $key => $metatag) {
$metatag_description = [
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => [
    'name' => $metatag['name'],
    'content' => $metatag['content'],
  ]
];
drupal_add_html_head($metatag_description, 'description');
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The preferred way to add meta tags is using the meta tags module. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Or theme files as explained here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217880/how-do-i-add-a-meta-tag-in-head-head-section

Comment: It’s relevant! The issue is metags. Use ur votes responsibly!